# Modeling time in graph databases

Tags: graph, database-design, neo4j, data-modeling, graph-databases

I read in Neo4j documentation a [section](https://neo4j.com/developer/modeling-designs/#model-time-versions) about how to make queries that depends on time more efficient:

> One way to model time-specific data and relationships is by including
>   data in the relationship type. Because Neo4j is optimized specifically
>   for traversing relationships between entities, you can often improve
>   query performance by specifying a date as the relationship type and
>   only traversing particular dated relationships.

[image]

But I was wondering, using this technique you will have to repeat the same things any time you want to make the time-based-queries more efficient. For example if you want to query the posts created by specific user at specific date you have to add (similarly to `AirportDay`) something like `UserDay`.

My question is there a possible way to model time universally in your graph?, so that time become the main entry-point to query events and activities in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

There's no answer to modelling time universally in your graph. It depends on your use cases.

The example in your post is one way to optimise non-performant queries that traverse too many relationships of the same type from a node.

You could also store time as a property on the node, and index it.

And then there's the option of a timetree https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html

To summarise, it depends on your use cases- usually no need to prematurely optimise.